# I need a shell script

Tags: shell

I need a script for uncompressing file directory.logs .z.z.z.z.z.z to directory.logs

Comment: Are you sure you would know what this means if someone else had asked this?

Comment: I'm guessing the incredibly informative title is supposed to be "Need a shell script". As to the question, I don't have a clue what you're on about

Comment: Amazing. There are so many different reasons this question could be closed!

Answer (score 2):

hmmmm....gzip -d is a good start....

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of utilities that can help.  In UNIX you can use the `uncompress` command

http://sis.agr.gc.ca/cansis/procedures/tar.Z.html#2.1

You can also use http://www.7-zip.org/ to unpack the .Z file.  As mentioned by @ennuikiller, `gzip -d` works as well.